# I need an alternative for TextJoin (5000 character limit reached)

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, spreadsheet, textjoin

I'm using this formula to separate the values from a column into another:

`=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("|";TRUE;E1:E);"|";TRUE;TRUE))`

As the data has gone up, I arrived to an issue with the TextJoin function and I got an error that says: "Text result of TEXTJOIN is longer than the limit of 50000 characters".

The format of the data I'm splitting looks like this:
`Win | M001-P165-G130-T363- | M004-P150-G300-T221-T265-T301-T317- | M065-P148-G7-T15-T221-T301-T345- | M089-P32-G133-T59-T107-T131-T170- | M110-P98-G63-T111-T172-T214-T247- |`

I guess there might be a Query or something with Array Formulas that I could do to avoid this error but I don't have that knowledge yet. What can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: It seems you are joining texts then splitting. Why then you need to join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it with QUERY but you will need to use empty space as separator.

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(FILTER(E:E; E:E<>"");;9^9); " ")))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work just fine.
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(FLATTEN(SPLIT(E1:E;" | ";0));"where Col1<>''";0))

Comment: @player0 a little tidier, no?